# Handling Array returned from c++ dll to C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have this in my dll created in c++

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    char*  __stdcall hh()
{
    char a[2];
    a[0]='a';
         a[1]='b';
    return(a);
}
```

And this is how I am trying to handle code in c#

```
[DllImport(@"mydll.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]     
       public static extern IntPtr hh();
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr a = hh();
           //How to proceed here???
        }


    }
```

**Help in proceeding further.**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to print the array returend from c++ code in c#

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to handle such arrays. `char a[2]` is allocated on the stack in your C++ function and is destroyed as soon as you return from it. You should either pass an array from C# and fill it in the C++ code or allocate array in the heap and provide some means for freeing it.

When you have it correct the handling will depend on how you return the data from C++ code. If it's still IntPtr you could use Marshal.ReadByte methods to read characters from memory and use Encoding methods to convert those bytes into string if necessary.

```
const int bufferSize = 2; // suppose it's some well-known value.
IntPtr p = ...; // get this pointer somehow.
for (var i = 0; i != bufferSize; ++i)
{
  var b = Marshal.ReadByte(p, i);
  Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution as follows::

OUR C++ code goes as follows

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    char**  __stdcall hh()
{
 static char* myArray[3] = {"A1", "BB2", "CC3",};
    return myArray;
}
```

And C# goes as follows

```
[DllImport(@"ourdll.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]     
      public static extern IntPtr hh();
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr a = hh();
            int j = 0;
            string[] s=new string[100];
           do
           {
               s[j] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(a,4*j));
               j++;
           }
           while(s[j-1] != null);
        }
```

> The only problem now faced is that how can we know size of the array
>   so that in this statement 
>   **string[] s=new string[100];** 
>   we neednot waste our memory.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be

```
 string stra = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(a);
```

But you also have the problem that the dll returns garbage per your code as char* is a local c style string.
Would be ok if you would return something like:

```
 const char* str = "Hello from DLL.";
```

Comment: I want to pass array of strings not a single string

Comment: Ok. Misunderstood that bit. Hope helps anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use not empty StringBuilder as the return value.